# OS X Mavericks xcode-select install not working

Tags: xcode, terminal, osx-mavericks

I'm using a fresh install of Mavericks. I've installed xcode from the app store. Now I want to install HomeBrew. When I run xocde-select --install it returns

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

xcode-select -print-path returns

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and xcode-select -version it returns

```
xcode-select version 2003
```

Something seems wrong with that version, but I just pulled it down from the app store. Can someone point me in the right direction?